# JavaFX fire an event, when Node is "covered" by ScrollPane

Tags: javafx

I have a dynamically filled GridPane with rows and columns. The GridPane is in a ScrollPane, so if there are a lot of rows and columns to add, the user can scroll down and is able to see all information.

Is there a possibility to fire an event, when the first column or the first row is "fully covered" by the ScrollPane, so if the row (Node) is fully hidden?

My idea is, to start an animation, when the first row/columns is covered, so if there is a lot of information in the GridPane, and the user scrolls down, the first row will appear on the screen.

It could also help me, if there is a possibility to put ChangeListeners on the Dragable ScrollBar, so if the Bar was moved 100px down, it fires an event.

Best regards,